# tortoise svn tagging multiple files

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am using Totoise SVN for version control. I have a folder with the following structure:

Folder A -> File A (revisions 1, 2)

Folder B -> File B (revisions 3, 4)

I would like to create a folder in which  revision 1 of File B and revision 3 of File B are tagged, as per the following plan:

tags folder -> project X folder -> File A (revision 1) + File B (revision 3)

But I have many problems:

First, when in the Repo-Browser, right clicking on folders and files does not give me the option to tag/branch. This only works if they are checked out. Why?

Second, and more importantly, I have no way of tagging multiple files simultaneously. I go to a folder's log, highlight 1 revision and right click and get the tag/branch option, but not if I highlight two and then right click

I can do one file at a time, but when I try to tag the second file into the first's tag folder it gives me an error message saying the folder already exists. So I cannot do them simultaneously or one by one!

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In another post someone wrote, "It's not a bug that you can't tag multiple files at once but a feature. Just tag the whole folder. In Subversion, a tag is a simple link, unlike CVS where a tag is actually a full copy of the tagged files. That means you don't have to pick single files to tag just to save space - you won't save space but use more (because you create more links). Oh, and it actually *is* possible to tag multiple files at once: select the files in the repository browser, then drag them to the tag folder." But if I click + drag a file then how do I select a specific revision #?

Comment: Also, is copying the file according to this formula the same as tagging? How would the system distinguish between copying and tagging?

Comment: As an example, I tagged the first file and added it to a folder called "1.1". But when I try to tag the second file into the same folder I get an error message "Path... already exists".

Comment: In SVN tagging means copying. When you are using TortoiseSVN to tag something from your working copy, in the background a remote copy is done and from the repository browser the copy command can be used (there is no "Tag/Branch" button, because you are expected to know what you are doing when operating directly with the repository).

Comment: With the "Tag/Branch" (working copy) or "Copy" (repository browser) command you can tag multiple files at once, if they are contained in one folder. "Tag/Branch" will on a folder will create a tag with the full content of the folder. With "Copy" just select the files you would like to tag and copy them to the tag folder. https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html

Comment: I would recommend to follow the proposed repository layout from SVN with "trunk", "branches" and "tags" folders for every project. Then just, tag each project in its "tags" folder. To create a project consisting of tags of various projects you should use externals pointing to the desired tag. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this with TortoiseSVN is to create a tag on the trunk (or the relevant revision of the trunk if you want to tag versions older than the version in your working copy), then use the Repo Browser to edit the tag and delete all the folders and files from it that you don't want the tag to reference.